# Text not showing and slider images missing

Tags: html, windows, css, browser, safari

I am trying to solve these issues, but I can't.

1. On this page, text is not showing in the Windows Safari browser: http://www.instyledirect.com/gallery.php
2. On the second page, some slider images are not showing: http://www.instyledirect.com/gold-gallery.php

Comment: Please provide an excerpt of your code that you think contains the problem. Show us what you tried already.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure?
For me it's showing everything.

Try with some Safari extensions.

Had the same problem, check out [Safari Show Error](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204098).
Maybe it would help you.

Clean also your Cache!!